# Google Maps JS v3: detect load failures

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I'm loading Google Maps using [this technique](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async) with code roughly as follows (using jQuery):

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_CLIENT_ID + "&v=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_API_VERSION + "&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&callback=googleMapsOnLoad",
                crossdomain: true,
                dataType: 'script'
            });
```

where `window.googleMapsOnLoad` is my handler for a successful load.

And it works fine generally but there are times where for some of my users, as best I can tell, it just doesn't load properly. Is there some way to attach an error callback that will fire if the load fails in some way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no real way to check, because sometimes it could take a long time for some resources to load (processor, connection speed, etc..). A way to handle this is by setting a proper timeout at a finite time (the following suggest 5 seconds).

```
function checkGMapsLoad() {
    if( !window.googleMapsOnLoad ) {
        //Error, Google Maps hasn't loaded yet. Reload page?
        //Stuff to perform here
    }
}

window.setTimeout( checkGMapsLoad, 5000 );
```

**Edit:** Since you're using jQuery to make the call, `jQuery.ajax()` has a parameter `error` that can be used incase the callback fails.

```
            $.ajax({
                url: "//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?client=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_CLIENT_ID + "&v=" + GOOGLE_MAPS_API_VERSION + "&sensor=false&libraries=geometry&callback=googleMapsOnLoad",
                crossdomain: true,
                dataType: 'script',
                timeout: 5000,          // <------ Optional
                error: checkGMapsLoad  // <------
            });
```

[jQuery.ajax() Documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Comment: Yeah, I see. I guess I was expecting there to be some kind of failure callback, equivalent to the `error` callback if performing a simple jQuery Ajax request (which it would be nice if this was).

Comment: True, that would at least handle the case where the initial script failed. I guess I have to trust that once Google takes over it can't possibly fail :)

Comment: I'm sorry, I totally overlooked the fact that you were using jQuery. Luckily @Dan, they have that covered too. Updated my answer.

Comment: As I said, that'll help but since Google maps involves loading a whole chain of stuff (which is why that callback is needed) I'm wondering what happens if something breaks part way down the chain.

Answer (score 1):

You may try something like this, ([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/8mxUU/6/)):

```
function initialize()
{
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 8,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(-34.397, 150.644)
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}
```

For cross domain script tag the `error` event does not fire, so `window.setTimeout` is used:

```
$(function(){
    var timeoutId;
    timeoutId = window.setTimeout(function() {
        alert("Script Error!");
    }, 2000);
    var url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
    $.getScript(url, function(){ window.clearTimeout(timeoutId) });
});
```

Comment: I'm just worried about what that timeout ought to be - some of my users are on remarkably slow connections.

Comment: Then increase the value in this case, may be (5000), no problem because once the script is loaded then the `timeout` would be cleared so fastest users won't see it.